# Inner join with different data type SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have some tables, let's call them table `GroupMember`

```
ID GroupID  Username
1   1        Frey
2   2        Anne 
3   2        Bryan
4   3        Belle
5   3        Will
6   4        Drio 
7   5        Maxio  
8   5        James
```

And this is table `Mailbox`

```
ID FromUser ToUser  Message  Approval
1  Belle    Client  Hello    Group 2
2  Anne     Client  Hai      Group 1
3  Maxio    Client  Hii      Group 4
4  Drio     Client  hey      Group 1
```

I want to `select * from Mailbox where (GroupID=1)`

So, `if GroupID=1` it will show this result:

```
ID FromUser ToUser  Message  Approval
2  Anne     Client  Hai      Group 1
4  Drio     Client  hey      Group 1
```

And the problem is data type of `GroupID` is INT and data type of `Approval` is NVARCHAR. How do I solve it?

Comment: This is a poor design.  Approval should be the same data type as the GroupID, and should likely have a Foreign Key constraint.

Comment: Because i have other tables which contain column that relationship with the GroupID in datatype INT, so i used the datatype INT @devlincarnate

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  Approval should not be NVARCHAR.  It should be INT, and likely have a FK constraint.

Comment: In addition, your mailbox table of fromUser and ToUser should be the foreign keys to the actual users.  What if you have 27 "John" users..  Retain the ID to the respective sender / recipient.  You can always join back to the user table to get the name when needed and would be very fast via indexes on the PK anyhow.

Comment: but the column approval must have a word 'Group' it means the column must have datatype nvarchar @devlincarnate

Comment: Having the word "Group" is part of the design flaw, not a reason for it.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear, from the data you have provided, the only column which links `MailBox` to `GroupMember` is the `Username` - which is a bad way to link tables because frequently you want to allow duplicate user names. Really your MailBox table should be storing the UserId and then joining on the GroupMember to obtain the username. `GroupID` does not appear to have any relationship to `Approval` based on the expected results - so I don't know why you are trying to join on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String functions`. Taking into account that field Approval consists of *'Group'+ Number* you can `Replace`
'Group' and `Cast` string to number:

*Using Join*:

```
 SELECT * FROM Mailbox
 JOIN GroupMember
 ON  CAST(REPLACE(Mailbox.Approval,'Group ','')AS INT)=GroupID
 WHERE GroupID=1
```

*Without Join (get the data from Mailbox with GroupId=1)*:

```
SELECT * FROM Mailbox WHERE CAST(REPLACE(Mailbox.Approval,'Group ','')AS INT)=1
```

*OR using Concat*:

```
 SELECT * FROM Mailbox
 JOIN GroupMember
 ON Mailbox.Approval=CONCAT('Group ',GroupMember.GroupID)
 WHERE GroupID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select *
from Mailbox m
inner join GroupMember g on g.GroupID = cast(right(m.Approval, 1) as int)
where m.Approval = 'Group 1'
```

Comment: Thankyou for helping me, but i just want to select where `GroupID=1` not `Approval =  'Group 1'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't select from Mailbox using the column GroupId because that table doesn't have that column, still if you want to select just using the number you could use a [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Mailbox
WHERE Approval LIKE 'Group ' + @id
```

Also, if you want to join the tables you can do it the same way

```
SELECT *
FROM Mailbox AS M
JOIN GroupMember G ON M.Approval LIKE 'Group ' + G.GroupID
```

I recommend you to use some other way to concatenate the value to the LIKE statement like the [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. But using a + operator would work in most SQL engines and versions.

Comment: Based on the question, you don't need the leading `'%'` which, when removed, makes the query sargeable. In fact you don't need like at all. PS - whats with `JOIN TABLE`?

Comment: Oh right, in this case the wildcard is not required. The `JOIN TABLE` is from a test that made its way here without me noticing. Thank you for telling me.